# Folder Compression in SSIS

Tags: ssis, compression, sql-server-2008-r2

How do I compress an entire folder in 2008 SSIS R2?

I cannot use any third party compression programs on my server.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't done this myself but it looks like you can script it with GZipStream:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx

Example code on there should be useful, it shows how to use the GZipStream class to compress and decompress a directory of files

EDIT:  Looks like that only works on the contents of the folder - not the folder itself so certainly not an ideal solution.

Comment: I have to compress a folder structure with all it's sub folders and files included. I had no choice but to go with a third party exe (Winzip).

Comment: Yeah I looked around some more and didn't see anything other than third party libraries for scripting it.  7-Zip is another good alternative I've used 7-zip and winzip with the command line add-on and been happy with both.